# PHP Regex or Dom Solution for screen scraping a website

Tags: php, regex, dom, screen-scraping

I have a page I need to pull data from that has the following format for the portion I need:

```
<td style="font-weight:bold;">Business Information</td><td id="BusInfo" colspan="2">Some Company<br /><br />Business Phone Number: (111) 111-1111<br /><br />111 Some STREET<br />Some City, AA 11111<br /></td>
```

I can get all the data except the Street. Dom puts all the line breaks into one array element and my regex:

```
$comregex = '/<br \/><br \/>(.*?)<br \/>/';
```

Is pulling just the phone number. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Its probably worth looking in to using `DOMDocument` ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) & an xpath to retrieve the results. Possibly soothing along the lines of `$Xpath = new DOMXpath(DOMDocument::loadHTML($htmlz)); $xpath->query("/html/body/td[@id='BusInfo']");`

$xpath = $doc);

Comment: I don't understand what you want can you clarify?

Comment: @Carl: No need to use xpath when you have the id value.

Comment: I just need to extract the business street address part using Dom or RegEx, or any other method :) I can pull the business name, phone number, city, state, and zip, just not the street address.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, it broke each 
 into an array for me and was able to pull the street address out.

```
$comregex = '/(.*?)br \/>(.*?)<br \/(.*?)/';
```